# Column search in multiple tables using datatables

Tags: jquery, datatables

I want to search inside the second column of two tables that are using datatables plugin. From [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20509032/search-multiple-tables-using-datatables) post, i get that i can use

```
$('table').DataTable().search(this.value).draw();
```

to perform search across my tables. As i wanted to search for items in the second column, i tried

```
$(".dtable").DataTable().column(2).search($(this).val()).draw();
```

But then ,it only works for the first table. Is there a way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Store reference of two datatables in a variable

```
var table1 = $('table').DataTable();
var table2 = $(".dtable").DataTable();
```

bind key event with search text box and apply search to second column of each table

```
$('input[type=search]').on( 'keyup click', function () {
      table1
        .column('2')
        .search(this.value, true, false, true )
        .draw();

     table2
        .column('2')
        .search(this.value, true, false, true )
        .draw();
    });
```

Comment: So it's impossible to do it in a global search!(?)

Comment: you can do it in global search, as i mentioned in above post just bind keyup event handler with global search input. you can find the class or id of it by inspecting the element in browser console. If you can provide jsfiddle or code snippet of your datatable then i can tell you the exact code

Comment: I was using dtable class for the two tables and the search for both the tables was bound to the keyup event. I was hoping there was a way to do it in a single statement . Well,this is working perfectly. Thanks.

Comment: happy to help you :), you can upvote and accept this answer if you find it useful